# The sides of a triangle are $n$, $n-1$, and $n+1$, for natural $n$, and angles $A$, $2A$, $\pi-3A$. Find $n$.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Problem:

> $\triangle ABC$ is such that $AB=n$, $AC=n-1$, $BC=n+1$ (with $n$ a natural number) and angles $A$, $2A$, $\pi-3A$. Find $n$.
>
> The answer is $n=5$.

My try:

By the Law of Cosines we have:

$$\begin{align}
n^{2} &=(n-1)^{2}+(n+1)^{2}-2(n^{2}-1)\cos (\pi-3A) \\
(n-1)^{2}&=n^{2}+(n+1)^{2}-2n(n+1)\cos A \\
(n+1)^{2}&=n^{2}+(n-1)^{2}\cos (2A)
\end{align}$$

I know that 
$$\cos(\pi-3A)=-\cos(3A)=3\cos A-4\cos^{3}A \quad\text{and}\quad \cos(2A)=2cos^{2}A-1$$

From the second equation we have

$$\cos A=\frac{n+4}{2(n+1)}$$

But when I applied I can't get correct answer.

> I'm searching a simple way to find $n$.

---

And we can generalized for sides $4k$, $5k$, $6k$ ($k$ a natural number).

Comment: When you state "Angles: $A, 2A, \pi -3A$", do you mean $\measuredangle A=A, \measuredangle B=2A,\measuredangle C=\pi -3A$?

Comment: Yes sir @YNK ! That what I mean!

Comment: Check the eqns 
$(n-1)^2=\dots\cos(A)$,
$(n+1)^2=\dots\cos(2A)$.

Given $|AC|=n-1,\ |BC|=n+1$
and $\angle A=A, \angle B=2A$,
they supposed to be
$(n-1)^2=\dots\cos(B)=\dots\cos(2A)$,
$(n+1)^2=\dots\cos(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

By law of sines:
$$\frac{\sin\alpha}{n-1}=\frac{\sin2\alpha}{n+1},$$ which gives
$$\cos\alpha=\frac{n+1}{2(n-1)}.$$
Also, $$\frac{\sin\alpha}{n-1}=\frac{\sin3\alpha}{n}$$ or
$$\frac{n}{n-1}=3-4\sin^2\alpha$$ or
$$\frac{n}{n-1}=3-4+\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n-1)^2}$$ or
$$n^2-n=-n^2+2n-1+n^2+2n+1.$$
Can you end it now?

You made a mistake for $\cos2\alpha$.
$$\cos2\alpha=\frac{n^2+(n-1)^2-(n+1)^2}{2n(n-1)},$$ which gives
$$\cos2\alpha=\frac{n-4}{2(n-1)}.$$

Comment: thanks! But you know $A<π-3A<2A$ ??! My be $A<2A<π-3A$ ?? I have a problem in this ? I can take $A-->n$ and $2A-->n-1$, $π-3A-->n+1$ as we like ??

Comment: @Ellen Ellen Can, I got it, but you want a value of $n$ only. I got $\alpha=\arccos\frac{3}{4}.$

Comment: whene I take $A-->n-1,2A-->n,π-3A-->n+1$ I got different answer $n=2$ ?? Why !?

Comment: @Ellen Ellen I added something. See now.

Comment: thanks!! so I all case we get negative number $n$

Comment: @Ellen Ellen Also, for $n=2$ we obtain the following sides: $2,1,3,$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

By the sine theorem, we have: $\frac{n-1}{sinA}=\frac{n+1}{sin2A}=\frac{n}{sin(\pi-3A)}$
Using the equality of the first and second relations, as well as the formula for the sine of the double argument, we find $cosA=\frac{n+1}{2(n-1)}$ `(*)`;
You have already found $cosA=\frac{n+4}{2(n+1)}$ `(**)`;
Equating the right-hand sides of equalities (*) and (**) we obtain an equation that gives a single root $n=5$

Comment: Thank you sir @rakurs77 but I'm asking why $A<π-3A<2A$ ??

Answer (score 0):

If $\angle A=A, \angle B=2A, \angle C=\pi -3A$, there is no solution.

If $\angle A=2A, \angle B=A, \angle C=\pi -3A$, then by the Sine theorem:
$$\frac{n-1}{\sin A}=\frac{n+1}{\sin 2A}=\frac{n}{\sin (\pi -3A)}$$
From the first:
$$\frac{\sin 2A}{\sin A}=\frac{n+1}{n-1} \Rightarrow \cos A=\frac{n+1}{2n-2}$$
From the second:
$$\frac{\sin(\pi -3A)}{\sin A}=\frac{n}{n-1} \Rightarrow 3-4\sin^2A=\frac{n}{n-1} \Rightarrow \\
3-4\left(1-\left(\frac{n+1}{2n-2}\right)^2\right)=\frac{n}{n-1} \Rightarrow \\
12(n-1)^2-4[4(n-1)^2-(n+1)^2]=4n(n-1) \Rightarrow \\
4n^2-20n=0 \Rightarrow n=5.$$

Comment: thanks! Why in first case no solution ? You mean $A<π-3A<2A$ ??h how you know ??

Comment: the relationship of the three angles does not matter. The three sides and the angles opposite to them matter only. The first case produced negative $n$.

Comment: @Farruhoa Ooh so we always try ? Thank you very much , but In some case I take $n=2$ why ?

Comment: if question is correctly stated, no trial is necessary. In your case, it looks you miscopied/misinterpreted the question. Both other answers assume $\angle A=2A, \angle B=A$, which is not what you stated.